# How websites understand when they should show a captcha?

Tags: c#, http, recaptcha, captcha

As I mentioned in the title, for example when I log in to a website using my web browser it doesn't ask me to resolve a captcha. But when I log in using C# with HTTP requests, it asks for resolve a captcha. At first, I thought maybe I'm not sending some of the headers and that's why it asks for a captcha but even after sending all the headers that my web browser sends, it still asks for resolve a captcha. What's the reason for that? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Probably `User-Agent`, or perhaps some Javascript, etc. Unfortunately, it would depend on the website in question.

Comment: `User-Agent`, or count of requests in a window of time from a given IP, are common ways.

Comment: I actually tried copying the user-agent that my browser sends and using it, but I still had a captcha. Also, @mjwills is it possible to pass the algorithm you mentioned using C#?

Comment: @emrecmd To be fair, the whole point of captcha is to detect that it isn't dealing with a human. You aren't a human (since you are sending it in an automated way) - so it seems to have done its job. ;)

Comment: Why are you trying to bypass the captcha? What website are you interacting with?

Comment: I just learned using HTTP requests and that kind of stuff in C#, so I was just playing around. I tried a few websites and had the same result, so I wondered the reason, and here I'm asking. :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be cookies.  If you have visited a site before, your computer will already have cookies placed there last time you visited, and possibly even one that say 'this is a human'.

Your C# code will not have that unless you have configured the code to send (upon connection) and stored (when received).

Comment: Thanks for your answer first of all. What if I use cookies that my web browser sent? Would that help?

Comment: As I said, it's a guess.   One option would be to try it.   Read all the cookies for whatever site you are accessing via your browser, and then pass them as part of your request.   If your requests /exactly/ match the browser request, then the server will not know it's your code.